# Adding ASP.NET buttons to List<T> in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 `asp:button`s called `Show` and `Submit`. They are declared in the `.designer.cs` as:

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Show;
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button Submit;
```

and I want to add them to a `List<Button>`:

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> {Show,Submit};
```

It is not letting me do it. 2 errors show that

> a field initializer
>   cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property.

and the non-static objects are `Show` and `Submit`. So I thought I am not adding them to the list in the initializer.

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> ();
buttons.Add(Show);
```

But VS tells me `buttons` and `Show` are fields but I used them like a type. Can anyone tell me the correct way to do it?

---

the Class after changing the button names:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button> ();
        buttons.Add(btnShow);
// some click events below
}
```

---

**SOLUTION**:
The solution is: initialize the List or add elements to the List in `Page_Load`:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        private List<Button> tableButtons;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         tableButtons= new List<Button>();
         tableButtons.Add(btnSubmit);
            tableButtons.Add(btnShow);
        }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you're getting the error for that part of the code can you hit `F11` to launch the app and start debugging putting breakpoints  I tried your example in both winforms and webforms and cannot reproduce can you show more information i.e code what's the class header look like try changing the name of your button to `btnSubmit, btnShow`

Comment: Where is the code that is trying to add the buttons to the list? Is it in a static method?

Comment: @MethodMan just a standard webform class inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` with a `List<T>`, nothing special. And I don't think changing the names of the Buttons work either.

Comment: you have something else going on I can't tell unless I see your actual code.. can you actually open up a new web project and add the buttons using the tools menu..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got your code working, however I'd like to explain why so it can help you in the future.

The reason you're getting these errors is because your're trying to place your code within the class definition of `_Default`.  Within a class definition, you're allowed to define fields, properties, methods, and some other things that aren't worth getting into no, but the important thing is that you cannot place any arbitrary code in the definition.

You'll need to place your code inside a method of the class in order for it to compile and run properly.  However, since you're doing this within a webform, you'll need to also have your code invoked by either placing it inside of one of the [ASP.NET Lifecycle Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx#lifecycle_events), like Page_Load, or within a method that's called by one of the lifecycle events.

Hope this helps.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

if the buttons are on the same form you could do the following

```
List<Button> buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList();
```

or your original code

```
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>
{
    Show, Submit
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I put the `buttons` directly under the `.aspx.cs` class and and VS says the keyword `this` is not available in the current context. Also I do not want to add all controls of type `Button` to the `List<T>`, just 2 of them.

Comment: then if you only want 2 of them you could extend that to use a `.Where` but that's going to be a bit complex for you .. just use the new List<Button> syntax

Comment: show me what the Class looks like is this a public partial class..?

Comment: you are doing something wrong.. I just added `this.btnPrint.Text = string.Empty` creating a new web form and the code works just fine.. you must be doing something incorrect this line `buttons.Add(btnShow);` does not match up with what you declare Show did you change it to `btnShow and btnSubmit ?`

Comment: I actually figured it out myself. Thanks.